# A-Frame | Slide Bar

Tags: three.js, aframe

I was wondering what is the best way to create a slide bar in a-frame since there is no such feature, at least as  far as i looked at the documentation.

I would like to create something like this (taken from a unity project):

[image: Unity Slide Bar]

I can image that this could happen by import a line and a cylinder and play around with the position of the cylinder but i cant think of a way to count integers when moving right or left the cylinder..

P.S. It is my first day in A-Frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty complicated indeed, especially if it's your first day :) With a little search, I found [this component on github](https://github.com/rdub80/aframe-gui) could maybe answer your needs.

Comment: Did not tried it but the solution is sure there! Great Component! Will look deep into it. Thanks!